# How can I attach multiple AWS accounts to my Spacelift stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, spacelift

How can I connect my Spacelift stack to deploy resources into my multiple AWS accounts?

I have a current integration set up, and this works perfectly to deploy resources to my account but how can I attach multiple AWS accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is certainly achievable and here are some ways to get this accomplished:

- Have a Spacelift Cloud Integration associated with an IAM role in the
  shared services account that has [cross-account permissions to assume
  local IAM roles in the target AWS
  accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)
  (“Account A” and “Account B”).

  [Have the AWS Terraform provider assume the local AM
  roles](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#assume_role-configuration-block)
  (“acct-a” and “acct-b”) via the credentials for the “acct-ss” role.